# s3-ressource : how to specify content-type?

Tags: amazon-s3, concourse

I need to upload translations file asset on S3 using the concourse [s3-ressouce](https://github.com/concourse/s3-resource) with a "application/json" content-type.
Although, the content-type set in aws-s3 is always "binary/octet-stream".
It seems to be the default value set when concourse doesn't find any content-type specifications.

Here the related part of the pipeline.yml:

```
jobs:
- name: upload-en-translation-s3-dev
  serial: true
  plan:
  - get: github-branch-dev
    trigger: true
  - put: translation-dev-en
    params:
      file: github-branch-dev/blablabla/translations/en-*.json
      content_type: application/json
```

Does any one know how i should do to specify the content-type wanted ?

Comment: That actually looks correct. Are you not seeing the file uploaded with application/json content type?

Comment: no, that's my problem here... each time there is an upload, the file is tag with a binary/octet-stream content-type